# Aws s3 bucket static webhosting- css and js files not found in index.html

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, web-hosting

I have hosted a static website in the s3 bucket successfully, but CSS, JS files, and images paths are getting an error as below. Due to that UI not displayed proper.

[image]

All JS, CSS, and images are in the assets folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the exact settings of the bucket you used?

Comment: Static Web Hosting => Enabled,  
Permission access is => Public,
and bucket policy is as below 
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::frontend/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Need to enabled or disabled any settings, then let me know. = @Marcin

Comment: also, make sure the upper/lowercasing is correct - not all web hosts are case-sensitive, but s3 websites are.

Comment: case-sensitive is proper, I have checked.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 => I found the solution, the issue was the folder structure that I have not created on the S3 bucket.

```
assets/css/filename.css
assets/js/filename.js
```

create the same folder structure that has in your project and uploaded files on the respective folder.

Solution 2 => you can remove the path, instead, just put the filename in index.html
like this.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" lazyload="1">
```

It was working for me, both the solution.